# Googlebots causes JS errors, should I care?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-app-engine

On production server, I watch JS errors and send to the server:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onerror=function(msg,url,line) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }
    xmlhttp.open('POST', '/logJSerrorsHere', true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlhttp.send('msg='+encodeURIComponent(msg)+'&url='+encodeURIComponent(url)+'&line='+line);
    return true;
}</script>
```

and sometimes it logs some "mysterious" errors: "$ is not defined", but all of them comes from "googlebot(at)googlebot.com" or spiderbot. Should I deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

Depends :) If your site is readable and indexable with out Javascript (and your site is visible in search) I wouldn't worry too much about it, unless you feel the error is indicative of a bigger issue. You can test this using [Fetch and Render](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066467?hl=en) in Google Webmaster Tools.

If your site relies on Javascript to render the page (i.e. it uses AngularJS for example) then yes, fix it.

Comment: of course, it works normally. It seems that BOT doesnt include the external .js stuffs

Comment: Are those JS assets excluded by robots.txt? External page assets won't be included if the googlebot isn't allowed to access them.